# Ag Grid editable field becomes editable on a single click. Clicking on the field and pressing backspace clears the field

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

Here are the steps to reproduce.

1. Go to https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/cell-editing/
2. Click on any cell and press backspace.
3. Cell is empty.

How to make it editable only on double click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `suppressKeyboardEvent` property in the column definition, which lets you choose which events to suppress.

See the documentation: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/keyboard-navigation/#suppresskeyboardevent

For example, this prevents all keyboard events unless the user is in edit mode:

```
suppressKeyboardEvent: function (params) {
  return !params.editing;
}
```

Full example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-select-column-8ehfb6?file=index.js